# Problemas ao inicializar um tipo dentro de uma consulta com LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

Estou passando pelo seguinte problema, estou montando uma API para uma aplicação de forum e essa API precisa de um *endpoint* que retorne uma coleção de `Forum` que possuem a propriedade `ParentId` nula. Então montei o seguinte *endpoint*:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("toplevel")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllTopLevel(int page = 1, int pageSize = 15)
{
    var data = Db.Forums
        .Where(f => !f.ParentId.HasValue)
        .OrderByDescending(f => f.Name)
        .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .Select(f => new ForumDTO
        {
            Id = f.Id,
            Name = f.Name,
            SubForums = f.SubForums.Select(sf => new ForumDTO
            {
                Id = sf.Id,
                Name = sf.Name
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();

    return Ok(data);
}
```

Mas estou tendo problemas no `Select` desse LINQ, que está causando uma `NotSupportedException` com a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> The type 'ZigForum.Models.DTOs.ForumDTO' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

Classe `Forum`:

```
public class Forum
{
    public Forum()
    {
        SubForums = new List<Forum>();
        Posts = new List<Post>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public virtual Forum Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Forum> SubForums { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Classe `ForumDTO`:

```
public class ForumDTO
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parent_id")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created")]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parent")]
    public ForumDTO Parent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subforums")]
    public List<ForumDTO> SubForums { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("posts")]
    public List<PostDTO> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Já tentei algumas coisas também, como por exemplo inicializar a propriedade `SubForums` com `null`, já que na mensagem de erro anterior fala que um tipo só pode ser inicializado em dois lugares se em ambos os lugares valores forem atribuídos às mesmas propriedades e na mesma ordem. Fazer isso me pareceu comprimir com as exigências:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("toplevel")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllTopLevel(int page = 1, int pageSize = 15)
{
    var data = Db.Forums
        .Where(f => !f.ParentId.HasValue)
        .OrderByDescending(f => f.Name)
        .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .Select(f => new ForumDTO
        {
            Id = f.Id,
            Name = f.Name,
            SubForums = f.SubForums.Select(sf => new ForumDTO
            {
                Id = sf.Id,
                Name = sf.Name,
                SubForums = null // Note que fiz a alteração aqui
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();

    return Ok(data);
}
```

Mas me resultou em outro erro:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ZigForum.Models.ViewModels.ForumDTO, ZigForum, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor? Não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: já tentou `SubForums = new List<ForumDTO>()`?

Comment: @TobyMosque também não funciona, é uma restrição do LINQ to Entities

Comment: normalmente eu uso o `AutoMapper` para preencher as minhas DTO/Contratos, postei uma resposta com um exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode inicializar um objeto dentro de uma expressão Linq. Simples assim.

Mas, há como contornar:

```
public class ForumDTO
{
    // Propriedades

    public static ToForumDTO(Forum f)
    {
        return new ForumDTO 
        {
            Id = f.Id,
            Name = f.Name,
            SubForums = f.SubForums
        }
    }
}
```

E consome no seu Linq assim:

```
 .Select(ForumDTO.ToSubForum).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Estou vendo que a sua Entidade e o seu DTO tem as mesmas propriedades com tipos compativeis e o mesmo nome.

Neste caso, você pode tentar usar o [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) para fazer o mapeamento para você.

abaixo segue um exemplo usando LINQ para Objetos, mas deve funcionar sem problemas com LINQ to Entities.

**Entidade**

```
public class Forum
{
    public Forum()
    {
        this.SubForums = new List<Forum>();
    }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }        
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Forum Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Forum> SubForums { get; set; }
}
```

**DTO**

```
[DataContract]
public class ForumDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Guid? ParentID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ForumDTO Parent { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IList<ForumDTO> SubForums { get; set; }
}
```

**Global.asax - Registrando os Maps**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Forum, ForumDTO>();
}
```

**Consulta**

```
var forums = new List<Forum>();
PopularForums(ref forums);

var data = (
    from forum in forums
    where !forum.ParentID.HasValue
    select Mapper.Map<ForumDTO>(forum)
).ToList();
```

Se mesmo assim não dê certo, você pode fazer um `ToList()` antes de fazer o map.

```
var forums = new List<Forum>();
PopularForums(ref forums);

var lista = (
    from forum in forums
    where !forum.ParentID.HasValue
    select forum
).ToList();

var data = Mapper.Map<List<ForumDTO>>(lista);
```

Você pode ver o exemplo completo no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G1lVVX), note que ele serializa a arvore completa dos forums, indepedente do numero de parentes e subarvores.

Comment: Interessante, vou tentar fazer dessa forma utilizando AutoMapper, mais tarde te dou um retorno, pois não vou poder testar isso agora.

Answer (score 1):

Crie um conversor estático explícito na sua classe ForumDTO que converta o Fórum para o ForumDTO e na sua instrução select use-o. Também seria interessante você substituir boa parte dos métodos por instruções LINQ que imitam o SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Pode sim inicializar um objeto dentro do select.
Dá uma olhada nesse código, funciona perfeitamente.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const int page = 1;
        const int pageSize = 15;

        var forums = new List<Forum>
        {
            new Forum
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Forum 1",
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                SubForums = new List<Forum>
                {
                    new Forum {Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "Forum 2"},
                        new Forum {Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Name = "Forum 3"}
                }
            }
        };

        var data = forums
            .Where(f => !f.ParentId.HasValue)
            .OrderByDescending(f => f.Name)
            .Skip((page - 1)*pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .Select(f => new ForumDTO
                    {
                        Id = f.Id,
                        Name = f.Name,
                        SubForums = f.SubForums.Select(sf => new ForumDTO
                                                       {
                                                           Id = sf.Id,
                                                           Name = sf.Name,
                                                           SubForums = null
                                                       }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();

        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.Name);

            if (d.SubForums.Count <= 0) continue;

            foreach (var subForum in d.SubForums)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t"+ subForum.Name);
            }
        }       
    }
}

public class Forum
{
    public Forum()
    {
        SubForums = new List<Forum>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual Forum Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Forum> SubForums { get; set; }
}

public class ForumDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    public ForumDTO Parent { get; set; }
    public List<ForumDTO> SubForums { get; set; }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/071eSl

Comment: Cara, você esta usando o Linq em uma collection normal, o problema dele é porque ele esta usando linq to entity onde _"o linq vira uma consulta SQL"_, ou seja o _provider_ não está conseguindo interpretar o linq.

Comment: Tenta assim: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ULn8ny

Só restando passar o Db.
Não tenho como testar aqui, mas pode funcionar.

Comment: Lol, eh diferente, ele está usando outro provider para linq, **EF**

Comment: O problema dele está no ````ToList()```` dentro do linq,